# Run Selenium on Ubuntu server throws connection refused

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, webdriver-manager

I've been developing a .NET Core application which uses selenium to crawl some websites. Now it's time to deploy the application and I'm using Ubuntu 22.0.4. The code is running without any problem in my machine either using ChromeDriver or FirefoxDriver. However, the both options throw the exact same error in the server, which is:

```
Connection refused [fe80::f03c:93ff:fe7a:b1a%2]:43559 (localhost:43559)
```

I already tried several things without success. I'm using `Xvfb` to emulate a display.

Finally I let you with the full console's output:
[image]

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72649999/3099733 `xvfb` should be the right solution but you may use a wrong command.